# Which is the correct place to store master data

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am working on a spring MVC web application. There is some master data  for example currency code INR which I require on jsp page to compare with data from form bean. So which should be the correct place to store master data. Should it be in property file or do I need to fetch it from database and store it in any of the scope ?
Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: You should keep environments variables in your properties file and business data in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't expect to change data often then the property file is a fine place as a start. It is the simplest in terms of development effort. But note that to change the data you will need to restart the application.

Also if the application is running on multiple machines then each machine will have separate properties file. So you will have to edit properties files on all machines.

The database is better if you want to expose functionality to update the configuration to end-users. Also, the database will act as a single source of truth, no matter how many application nodes you have.
By currency codes, do you mean data like https://www.iban.com/currency-codes.html ?

In that case, it is a small amount of data that does not change often. 
So the properties file is ok. To inject properties as a map (unknown number of keys, unknown exact key values) you need to use @ConfigurationProperties as described in https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-loading-yaml

I would go for a database if it is used by your project for other purposes. Otherwise, I would go for the properties file.

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments, business data belong in the database, even if you change them every other year. Property files are a great place for technical properties, especially those that are required *before* you load the Spring context. Those might be database credentials, logging level etc.

Consider that if you start to load-balance your application on different hosts, you'd have multiple property files, too. Imagine you forgot to update the currencies in one of them, you're gonna screw up the consistency of your whole database, when each instance of your app calculate different prices.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using yml/properties files with [Spring Cloud Config](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/). It's simple enough to use and it will give you a way to update your properties in runtime, without redeploying or even restart. So don't forget to enable [Spring Actuator endpoints](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html) and get familiar with `@RefreshScope` annotation.